# How to make pop up disappear when clicked off of pop up?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I am creating a pop-up for my products when an icon is clicked. I want to make it so that the pop-up automatically disappears once the user clicks somewhere outside of the pop-up box. Currently, the only way for the pop-up to close and disappear is to click the same icon button that makes the pop-up appear to begin with. Id appreciate it if you could help me by using the code I provided as I am a beginner and will probably not be able to incorporate general suggestions but I will of course try my best! Thank you guys so much for the help and suggestions in advance.

**HTML Pop up Code**

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="icons"> 
            <a href="#contact" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
            <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
                <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">RAW Pipe Cleaners are naturally strong and absorbent and wrapped around a flexible banded iron core. These are the natural way to clean your pipe or rig! A RAW Innovation!</span>
            <a href="#" class="fas fa-info">
              </a></div>
            <a href="#" class="fas fa-eye"></a>
        </div>
```

**Pop Up CSS Code**

```
        /* Popup container */
        .popup {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        /* The actual popup (appears on top) */
        .popup .popuptext {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 8px 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            bottom: -740%;
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -150px;
            height: 400px;
            font-size: 18px;
            padding: 50%;
        }
        
        
        
        /* Toggle this class when clicking on the popup container (hide and show the popup) */
        .popup .show {
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
            animation: fadeIn 1s
        }
        
        /* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity: 1;}
        }
        
        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity:1 ;}
        }
```

**Pop up JS Code**

```
            // When the user clicks on <div>, open the popup
        function myFunction() {
            var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
            popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/128761) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new variable and state that when the user clicks outside of the popup area it auto-closes.

```
      window.onclick = function(event) {
         if (event.target == popup) {
        popup.style.display = "none";
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to make it so that the pop-up automatically disappears once the
> user clicks somewhere outside of the pop-up box

you can capture click event and check if it is clicked on your popup or outside of popup.

```
// Get the your popup
var popup = document.getElementById("mypopup");

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == popup) {
    popup.style.display = "none";
  }
} 


<div id="mypopup" class="box">
        <div class="icons"> 
            <a href="#contact" class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></a>
            <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
                <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">RAW Pipe Cleaners are naturally strong and absorbent and wrapped around a flexible banded iron core. These are the natural way to clean your pipe or rig! A RAW Innovation!</span>
            <a href="#" class="fas fa-info">
              </a></div>
            <a href="#" class="fas fa-eye"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```